# Video playback in Swift from URL

Tags: ios, swift, url, video-streaming, dropbox

I am currently trying to play a video on iOS from a URL in Swift. URLs with endings like ".mp4" or ".m4v" work, but when I try to play a shared video link from Dropbox it doesn't.
I already changed the ending of the Dropbox link to "dl=1" but anyway nothing happens.

Playing a Youtube-video in a webview is not a solution for me, because I want the native iOS player.

Does anyone know what to do to play URLs from Dropbox or maybe recommend cloud services where this does work?

Thank you!

Comment: and you don't want to use [SwiftyDropbox](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox)

Comment: No, I just need a good solution to have a video url to play in AVPlayer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know dropbox streaming spec.
But if dropbox url doesn't have hint for playing like mp4,
you can use AVAssetLoaderDelegate like proxy server.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloaderdelegate

AVAssetLoaderDelegate excute when url has custom scheme.
If you use "foo" scheme, 'shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource' will be called. And you should make another request for dropbox with same http header.

Try like this

```
func play() {
    let url = URL(string: "foo://bar.mp4")!
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

    player.play()
}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
    var newRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "dropbox url")!)
    newRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = loadingRequest.request.allHTTPHeaderFields

    let sessionTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newRequest) { data, response, error in
        if let responseData = data {
            loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: responseData)
        }
        loadingRequest.finishLoading() // Let player know that finish loding
    }

    sessionTask.resume()

    return true // Wait for sessionTask response.
}
```

Comment: In the "play"-function playerItem is never used and sessionTask in resourceLoader neither. I don't know how this should be implemented, would be nice if you could explain a little further

Comment: Thanks for the update. I first had to change "asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)" to "asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: queue: DispatchQueue.main)" otherwise it would crash. Afterwards it did load something but the video could not be played. Maybe it is because of the Dropbox link

Comment: Could you add more information for AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest? AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest is in loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.